# Integrating Grammarly with online LaTeX editors such as overleaf?

Tags: tools, online, grammar

[Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com) does not work with `LaTex`, but I believe it still can be helpful:

[image]

I like to use [Grammarly Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-for-chrome/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen?hl=en) with an online Latex editor. I tried [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com), [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) , [authorea](http://www.authorea.com) and [verbosus](http://www.verbosus.com) on Chrome. Even though the Grammarly icon on the top right seems active, it doesn't work:

[image]

If you have Grammarly installed and try to write a question/answer or comment while on a StackExchange website, you can see that it works (the small red or green circle on the bottom left of the text frame shows the number of errors and gives the proper hints).

Do you know any way to force Grammarly to work on Chrome or another browser / OS / Website ?

Comment: In meanwhile, I also tried http://papeeria.com/, http://www.publications.li/blue and 
http://cloud.sagemath.com/. still no success...

Comment: I've just asked Grammarly to add this feature. Currently, there is still no native solution for that.

Comment: @ignacio Thanks for initiating the feature request. Is there any way how to add any votes to this idea so that it becomes more popular?

Comment: There is now an official response about this from Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Use_Grammarly_with_Overleaf

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I used to copy and paste, as Hamid suggested until recently. I created a chrome extension that copies the .tex content; filters the commands/keywords and pastes the plain text in a textarea. This textarea is displayed over the pdf preview and all textareas are scanned by Grammarly.
[image]

It is not yet on the store, but you are able to install it if you are only a bit technical. You can find it here: https://github.com/robindijkhof/overleaf-textarea

EDIT: I created a new version. Changed made by Grammarly are automatically merged back to Overleaf. I published it to the Chrome store, it is currently waiting for a review.

EDIT: It is now available from the store. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/overleaf-textarea/iejmieihafhhmjpoblelhbpdgchbckil

EDIT: JFYI, it's also available for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/overleaf-textarea

Comment: Does it work for MacOs?

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli as long a you use either Chrome or FireFox

Comment: Is it possible to switch between PDF and the textarea?

Comment: Open the plugin and disable it

Comment: Hi @RobinDijkhof, I have a question about using your plugin. I have Overleaf open with Grammarly, and your plugin is activated as well. When I intentionally make a typo such as "amd" the plugin doesn't seem to recognize and suggest that I correct it. Is there something else that I'm missing such as having Grammarly premium or certain settings for Overleaf?

Comment: Any hope to have it on Opera as well?

Comment: I think it would be great if the math can also be filtered, or be replaced by some placeholder.

Answer (score 36):

In overleaf, if you select **rich text mode**, then Grammarly works when you write a comment. This screenshot shows the idea:

[image]

Update: to somehow make it faster to check, you may select the text you want to analyze and press the comment button so that the text goes directly in the comment and Grammarly checks it instantly.

Comment: Only works with comments? Why not the actual text?

Comment: better ask [Overleaf team](https://www.overleaf.com/about) and more importantely, [Grammarly team](https://www.grammarly.com/contact).

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. I can't comment from rich text,at least from firefox

Answer (score 26):

As a suggestion, I usually write the whole article then check all  of its content (all latex document) by Grammarly desktop and also languagetool (and also maybe some others) together to proofread it completely. Then, I refresh the file by copy and pasting the result into the editor (in my case texstudio but you may copy and paste in sharelatex).

Comment: the question is about how **to integrate** Grammarly. Your answer basically suggesting a manual copy and past .

Comment: Actually, I think this is an example of pen or pencil in space dilemma. My suggestion, instead of inventing pen for space use pencil if you don't have resources.

Comment: LanguageTool, i.e. the LanguageTool browser add-on, actually supports overleaf.com now (Disclosure: I'm the founder of LanguageTool).

Answer (score 21):

I just found a way to directly use Grammarly in Overleaf!
At the time of writing (Aug, 2022) this is still a beta feature which is being rolled out slowly though it is already [documented in their docs](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Use_Grammarly_with_Overleaf) and explicit opt-in to the beta program makes this available for everyone.

How to:

0. Install Grammarly plugin for Chrome.
1. Overleaf => Account => Account Setting => Overleaf Beta Program => Enroll
2. Go to your project
3. You will see an orange "beta" icon in the top-left corner of your editor. Select "Source (Beta)".
4. Done!

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: Added. This is the best day of my life LoL

Comment: It doesn't work 100% in Firefox (99.0.1).
In this example (left part of image), Grammarly, only finds one of the two mistakes. I guess this is due to the text being split among different tags in the HTML document (see right part of the image). Helpful nonetheless, thanks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtNpi.png

Comment: The Overleaf Beta program is the savior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wordeep, which works with Overleaf: https://wordeep.com

[image: wordeep for overleaf]

Comment: can you add some screenshots of your examples?

Comment: Thank you Sadegh, added a picture