# Grammarly for texstudio

Tags: texstudio, grammar

The Grammar Check of texstudio is Languagetool which is really not a grammar checker (although best in the opensource environment). I was wondering if anyone knows a way to connect one of the good grammar checkers to it. Grammarly and or ProWritingaid are examples that I like to be considered.

Edit:

Recently Grammarly released a version it calls Grammarly for Windows. This app directly operates in Windows applications. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to operate in Texstudio. Is there any way to benefit from it while writing in the texstudio?

Comment: Can't you just use any text editor that supports Grammarly and compile on the command line? If not, the question would better be directed to the TeXstudio mainainer(s).

Comment: which editor does support grammarly. Isn't texstudio the best?

Comment: I don't know which editor supports Grmmarly. I use `vim`, others use `emacs` others use something else. But using a (instant) grammar checker is not related to TeX or LaTeX at all.

Comment: @Hamid There are interfaces to Grammarly for Emacs atleast

Comment: I have the same problem. What I do, normally, is to copy/paste the text into the grammaly editor online. I think it is the only solution for now: the texstudio maintainers say that it "is NOT a priority" ( https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1175/ )

Comment: Still wanted and still dreaming: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/528

Answer (score 5):

You can use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as your editor for tex files and install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.grammarly) extension to get Grammarly support.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. I found the way as follows: When you need to check Grammarly, copy the TeX to https://www.overleaf.com/ and you can also edit and run the TeX in there (online). Then the browser will check this for you. I think this is the best way right now. Or you can use the checker by Texstudio, they have it. But it is very very basic.

Answer (score 4):

This is also a round-about solution, but I used Texstudio to write, fix spelling mistakes, and compile the pdf. Then I used Foxit Phantom PDF to convert it to Word (I know, I almost feel ashamed) but it gets me the results I want which is Grammarly checking my thesis paper. And while it is tedious, having Grammarly point out errors helps me to see my thesis with "fresh eyes" so to say. I do have to have the Word document with Grammarly open next to Texstudio so that I can make the changes in Texstudio as I make them in Word, but it does get the job done. A few iterations of this and my 100+ page thesis is finally presentable.

Comment: Why not just copy and paste the latex into Grammarly?

Comment: Grammarly used to catch a lot of the latex code and show it as a problem. For a short document, it isn't a big deal, but for a 120+ thesis paper, that means hitting "ignore" a lot. I don't know if Grammarly is better now and automatically ignores code, but it used to be an issue for me. I haven't tried recently.

Comment: I think MS Word 2016 onwards do a decent job of opening PDF documents, if you have a lot of equations they are messed up and grammarly complains about mathematical formula. But that is my workflow as well. There is a sort of plugin for VSCode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.grammarly  it doesn;t let you login to grammarly if you have a paid account though. It used to but something broke in the last year or so

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer is not for texstudio and I don't know if you have seen this or not, but recently, here is a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/overleaf-textarea/iejmieihafhhmjpoblelhbpdgchbckil) built by [this person](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/225959/robin-dijkhof) recently(Oct 3, 2020) who claims the extension works well with overleaf. Following is the link to the answer.
[Integrating Grammarly with online LaTeX editors such as overleaf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565255/228842)

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple, just copy the latex file with any latex editor like TexStudio. While the latex file is open, just select the whole latex code from \documentclass to \end{document} with Ctrl+A and then copy and paste it on a new word document with the Grammarly plugin for word installed. If you have not installed Grammarly plugin for word, download and install it for free. The errors will then show and you will correct them, then copy the whole code back to the latex file. See Below.

Download Grammarly plugin for word here for Windows users: https://www.grammarly.com/office-addin

[image]