# Apply Grammarly in TexShop (Latex) on a Macbook

Tags: texshop, online, grammar, software, offline

> Is there some way to apply the Grammarly in the TexShop (latex software for Mac), say on a MacBook Pro?

A related post is here: [How Integrate Grammarly on online latex editors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333947/how-integrate-grammarly-on-online-latex-editors)

I know that we can use Grammarly online, or use Grammarly as a Grammarly on the Macbook. There is an App you can download with this logo:

[image]

But I want to use it in a latex format on my computer directly.

It this is possible, would it matter for using that function of Grammarly for the free version or the Premium version?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how easy it may be for a current developer such as TeXtidote to offer Grammarly as an alternative to Language Tools  <strike>perhaps you could raise a feature request at</strike> https://sylvainhalle.github.io/textidote 
Looking through the issues raised there it is unlikely unless Grammarly changes significantly.

1) It appears that whilst I can open a local tex file or report.html or md file from the command line in Grammarly Desktop and  it will allow me to make changes, The TeXtidote developer finds the browser extensions are not accessible unless tex reports are physically online !

2) Both offer overlapping and similar functions, However Grammarly does not see anything near as much out of place in a TeX file than the more format dedicated TeXtidote.

I suggest you look at this as a TeX specific alternative solution.

To see how easy it is to add a suitable editor script to any TeX editor see my "Out Of Box" example here (yes **I know screenshot is not Mac TexShop** however **TeXtidote is cross platform** (java), so it should work on any TeX editor with the correct shell command.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment/answer +1 -- I did not vote down, but vote up.

Comment: Cheers I am on slow BBand and can inject as shown above a tex file into desktop app easily but Grammarlys web interface is a pain in the A's, spending more time hitting ignore than corrections. The simplicity of my suggestion is that its "offline" thus quicker to scan for stupid errors that can easily be corrected in the editor for a quick refresh.

Comment: I should have added you CAN adapt the above script mod to send the tex to Grammarly desktop in a similar fashion to more closely meet your request, and it does work faster and with less problems than the browser interface but you then need to cut and paste changes as its more difficult (though probably not impossible) to reinject the tex back into the editor since Grammarly does not export over the original file with the same filename. (That's probably for the best otherwise one false correction could skew compilation)